# cycle windows in current space, version Catalina

Tags: window-manager, mission-control

This functionality is the same as [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29130/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-cycle-between-windows-in-the-current-space)
Description:

- The given: In the current desktop there is one terminal and Safari open, and in another desktop there is another terminal window. Desired is to cycle open windows in the current desktop.
- The problem: When I use *preferences -> shortcuts -> keyboard -> center in active window or next*, (the default shortcut is ^F4 I think), in many cases it jumps to the terminal in the other desktop.

Notes:

- This happens with other apps that can open in sevaral windows. I raise terminal as an example.
- the `hs.expose` library of *hammerspoon* as mentioned in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127240/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-applications-in-mission-control#answer-356058) results the same.
- Please to not offer closed source software.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: As noted in your 2 linked questions & also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app this cannot be done natively. Spaces is simply not designed to allow one app to spread across multiple Spaces. Anything you do to try to fight that paradigm is going to have to come from a 3rd party app.

Comment: thanks Tetsujin. Can you say, please, what is the paradigm then?

Comment: One App to one Space.